# Post Method with NSDictionary Values using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection, alamofire

I'm completely new to`Swift`. I need to hit a Post Method webservice with `NSDictionary` parameters & get the JSON response. I tried using`Alamofire` & also `NSMutableUrlRequest`. Nothing seems to workout for me. I either get 'JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set' error or 'Undefined Variable' response from the server. The same service works fine when I try using `Objective-C`. As I said earlier, I am completely new to`Swift` & need your assistance.

My base url: http://myofficeit.in/bizfeed/webservices/client.php

Parameter I wanna Pass:

Parameter =

```
{
    UserName = xyz;
    deviceModel = iPhone;
    deviceToken = "949264bc cd9c6c851ee64cc74db9078770dd7d971618ec20ce91d2e6eb9f155e";
    emailid = "xyz@gmail.com";
    location = Asia;
    userMobileNo = 1234567890;
};
functionName = register;
```

The code I used for hitting the service is: http://pastebin.com/aaT4uhS7

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use like

```
let param: [String:AnyObject] = [
    "UserName": iPhone,
    "deviceToken": "949264bc cd9c6c851ee64cc74db9078770dd7d971618ec20ce91d2e6eb9f155e",
    "emailid": "xyz@gmail.com",
    "location": Asia,
    "userMobileNo": 1234567890
]

Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://myofficeit.in/bizfeed/webservices/client.php/register", parameters: param).responseJSON { (req, res, json, error) in
    print(req)
    print(res)
    print(json)
    print(error)
}
```

for sample request in [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

Comment: I'm using the latest version of AlamoFire. This actually throws ''Contexutal closure type response expects 1 arguments but 4 are used in closure body"

Comment: @Vignesh - check this link bro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384342/contextual-type-for-closure-argument-list-expects-1-argument-but-4-were-specifi

Comment: Thanks Bro. I'm getting this error now: Request failed with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0."

Answer (score 0):

As broad as your question is, the broad will be my answer:

The first thing to do, is to get a clear idea about the web service API, which also requires a basic knowledge of the HTTP protocol. So, what you need to understand is, what the server expects in HTTP terminology.

You eventually will find out, how the server will expect its "parameters". Note, that there is no term like "parameters" in the HTTP protocol. So, you need to map them into something the HTTP protocol provides.

Most likely, in a POST request, "parameters" are transferred as the body of the HTTP message, as a content-type which is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data` or `application/json`.

According to the needs of the server, and with your basic knowledge of HTTP and `NSURLSession`, `NSURLComponents` etc., you compose the URL and the body of the request, set `Content-Type` header and possibly other headers and you are ready to go.

How this eventually looks like is given in the answer of @AnbyKarthik, which used Alamofire, and a command that composes a POST request whose parameters are send in the body whose content-type is `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Thanks dude. Got an idea of it now.